# MYSQL 8 deployment failed in minikube .. container is not running .. mysqld failed while attempting to check config

Tags: mysql, containers, minikube, conf.d

After deploying mysql in minikube i am getting following error. and container is not up.

When I am deploying the app, it is deployed, but after deployment container is not running due to following error

```
2020-04-25 16:56:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-04-25 16:56:45+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
    command was: mysqld --verbose --help
    mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

my MySQL deployment file is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    name: mysql
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:latest
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "xxxxxx"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        hostPath:
          path: /mnt/data
```

Comment: Hi, can You share the events of the mysql pod by running `kubectl describe pod pod_name` command?